# Cumulative distribution function of sum of two continuous uniform distributions

Tags: probability

Two continuous uniform distributions U(0, 1), X and Y, independent. I want to find cumulative distribution function of X + Y without using convolution. It appears the calc for s between 1 and 2 is wrong (or maybe the 1st half is wrong too). The differentiation does not match 2 - s (the answer from convolution). Where did I miss? Thank you.

$F(s) = P(X+Y < s)$

$0 < s < 2$

$F(s) = \int_{ }^{ } \int_{0}^{s-u} 1 \ dvdu = \int_{ }^{ } s-u \ du $

$ for \ 0 < s < 1$

$F(s) = \int_{0}^{s} s-u \ du = \frac{1}{2}s^{2} $

$ for \ 1 < s < 2$

$F(s) = \int_{s-1}^{1} s-u \ du = -\frac{1}{2}s^{2} + s $

With the function, F(2) is 2, not 1. I hear the correct CDF is the following, but I cannot get there. Please help...

$F(s) = -\frac{1}{2}s^{2} + 2s -1 $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $1<s<2$, your limit of integration is not correct.

If you sketch out the region, you get the region the region of interest to be the unit square subtract away a triangle. The length of the triangle is $2-s$.

Hence

$$F(s) = 1-\frac{(2-s)^2}{2}$$

[image]

Edit:

We can split the integral into two parts:

$$\int_0^{s-1} \int_0^1 \, \, dydx + \int_{s-1}^1 \int_0^{s-x} \, \, dydx$$

Comment: Thank you. Could you please show F(s) = integral calculation with boundaries? I still do not understand the boundaries to use.

Comment: Thank you again. First, I apologize for a typo. The original problem's 3rd integral's lower boundary should have been s - 1, not 1- s. I fixed it. This has no meaningful impact to the problem. 

I tried your two-parts integral, but the result did not match with the answer. Also, could you kindly explain why we divide into two parts?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I made a mistake earlier. We divide into two parts as if we consider the vertical strip, sometimes the upper bound is $1$, sometimes, the upper bound is the  line $x+y=s$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand now.